# Java DateTimeFormatter - Adding days sometimes provides a wrong result

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeformatter

Currently we have implemented the following:

```
LocalDateTime actualDate = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
String fromDate = format.format(actualDate.plusDays(15));
String toDate = format.format(actualDate.plusDays(30));
```

Most of the time, it works perfectly fine. Sometimes, something wild appears as a Date - for example:

the toDate was correctly calculated to 09.04.2022 - but the fromDate was calculated as 02.20.9032, which seems totally odd.
Especially, as it only occurs occasionally, it is hard to understand what exactly is going wrong here.

I would kindly appreciate any advice or help on the same. If plusDays(15) works, it seems odd why plusDays(30) suddenly shouldn't and viceversa... and it does only rarely happen to be wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` when you seem to only care about the date and not the time? I suspect you might be running into some daylight-saving/timezone issues which you could totally avoid by telling Java that you care about  the date only.

Comment: you should probably find out which `actualDate` produces such weird errors

Comment: Hi, a good hint - will try to use LocalDate and monitor if it happens again.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` should work too. What Java version are you using?

Comment: Currently using java 11.0.11 2021-04-20 LTS

Comment: Could it happen that your variables can be assigned to form another thread?